# Add number to the ending of a numerical date value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, datetime-format

I'm trying to store an ID with the Date (month/day/year) in the same integer value in C#.

This way I can check whether a specific Id was already voted on in a particular day and prevent double voting in the same day. I store the votes in a static variable.

I convert the date to long using this code:

```
long.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

So for today (2/9/2015) I get: `20150209`

Now my IDs are integers. I want to append those to the converted date number.

So if for example the ID is 138, I want to add 138 to the end of the number, so the end result would be: `20150209138`.

How can I append the id to the converted numerical date like I've explained above?

Comment: `* 1000) + 138`, Probably not the best idea though to store numbers this way, you would be better off either with strings or an object model

Comment: @Sayse I want the search to be very quick, and I use MultiValueDictionary. so I can just do a search based on the key (ip) and value (e.g. 20150209138)

Comment: Plus 1 for using an object rather than fudging a numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+ID.ToString());
```